# Is there a way to get the line number of node from typescript compiler API?

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis, typescript-compiler-api

I know that we can get the position of a node using `node.pos` but is there a way of getting the line number of the node? Something like `node.lineNumber`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
let { line, character } = 
sourceFile.getLineAndCharacterOfPosition(node.getStart());
    console.log(`${sourceFile.fileName} (${line + 1},${character + 1}): 
${message}`);
```

From here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Using-the-Compiler-API.md

Comment: Note that depending on how `node` was created, you may need to pass `sourceFile` to `node.getStart` or you will get en error like `cannot read property 'text' of undefined`